# Getting Unique Id for a list

Tags: rest, sharepoint, ms-office, office365, onedrive

How can I get the UniqueId for a List?(say Documents list)

For a root level item(meaning this item is at the first level of Documents list) when I get its **ParentUniqueId**, it gives me the **UniqueId** of the list it lies under. 
Now my problem is that I'm unable to get the **UniqueId** for a list(when I get the meta for it) so that I can differentiate that this **ParentUniqueId** is either my list's **UniqueId**(which in this case is **Documents** list) or the **UniqueId** for another item which this item lies under(file within a folder or folder within a folder).

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that `ParentUniqueId` property stores the parent container id, in case of `List Item` the container is always **Folder**.

**Example 1:**

Assume the following structure for a Documents library:

```
Documents (library)
   |
   Document.docx (document item with id = 1)
```

Then the query:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items(1)/FieldValuesAsText?$select=ParentUniqueId
```

will return the value of `SP.List.rootFolder`.

> Note: the returned value corresponds to `Folder.UniqueId` and **not** to `List.Id`

The following queries demonstrate how to retrieve Documents library `RootFolder.UniqueId`:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/rootfolder/UniqueId
```

or

```
/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents')/UniqueId
```

**Example 2**

Assume the following structure for a Documents library:

```
Documents (library)
   |
   Orders (folder)
      |
      Document.docx (document item with id = 2)
```

Then the query:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items(2)/FieldValuesAsText?$select=ParentUniqueId
```

will return the `Folder.UniqueId` value of `Orders` folder.

The corresponding query to retrieve `Orders` folder `UniqueId` property:

```
/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/Orders')/UniqueId
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case the URL is >>> _api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents')/UniqueId